# Why does the sword I found still have a price tag on it, and what does it mean?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

Whenever I find a new item (so a couple times per minute), the name of the item appears briefly with a "price tag" showing a number of gold coins.  I thought it a bit strange that all these mercenaries hadn't even removed the tags from their equipment, but I was surprised when I found a shop and tried to "return" the item for store credit, they didn't offer me anywhere near the amount that had been on the price tag.

So if that number doesn't tell me how much gold the item is worth, what does it tell me?  Is the sale price some percentage of the value that is shown?

Comment: I know Dungeon Siege 3 is quite departed from its predecessors, and I have yet to play it, but in Dungeon Siege 2 there was a spell that could turn items on the ground into gold, the amount of which would be determined by your level with that spell class. Perhaps that tag is related to something similar in DS3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'price tag' is a basis for both selling at the merchant and transmuting the item into gold. I tested this theory in my game and here's what I came up with:

You will receive 15% of the item's 'price tag' value at the merchant.

If you transmute the item into gold then you will receive 5% of the 'price tag' value.

In Dungeon Siege 3, transmuting can be accomplished by hitting 'C', going into the 'items' tab and clicking the left mouse button over the item in which you wish to transmute.